# python hashlib.md5 escape characters

Tags: python, md5

Following snippet presents basic usage of python `hashlib.md5` (in py2.7).

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> m = hashlib.md5()
>>> m.update('phrase')
>>> m.digest()
'8Z\xa58^\x83\xef\xc5\xd8<u\x88\xee_\xb7\xe8'
>>> type(m.digest())
<type 'str'>
```

I've got two questions:

1. how can I transform the hex representation into human-readable text?
2. what is the reason for python not returning a simple hash like `385aa5385e83efc5d83c7588ee5fb7e8`? What is this escaped hex representation used for?

Comment: Are you actually after `m.hexdigest()` ? The binary version is more suited towards bit operations and is half the size than the human readable version...

Comment: Also you can output it by using the built-in function repr (it's useful when you have problems with output of the string, for example in a Jinja2 template): `repr( m.digest() )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1.: Just use `m.hexdigest()`.

See here for docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the *binary representation* of the hash digest. What you want is the hex digest, produced by [`hash.hexdigest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest):

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> m = hashlib.md5()
>>> m.update('phrase')
>>> m.hexdigest()
'385aa5385e83efc5d83c7588ee5fb7e8'
```

Python gives you access to both the original binary value and the hexadecimal representation.